# How to stop the gnome-keyring on Slackware?

Tags: slackware, gnome-keyring

My syslog is full of those messages

```
Nov 22 13:14:36 virtuale-2 gnome-keyring-daemon[2413]: couldn't create socket directory: /root/.cache/keyring-CI8ZC1: Permission denied
Nov 22 13:14:36 virtuale-2 gnome-keyring-daemon[2413]: couldn't bind to control socket: /root/.cache/keyring-CI8ZC1/control: Permission denied
Nov 22 13:14:40 virtuale-2 gnome-keyring-daemon[2421]: couldn't create socket directory: /root/.cache/keyring-LQDED1: Permission denied
Nov 22 13:14:40 virtuale-2 gnome-keyring-daemon[2421]: couldn't bind to control socket: /root/.cache/keyring-LQDED1/control: Permission denied
```

The process didn't exist!

```
pgrep -a keyr
pgrep -a gnome
```

Impossible to find from where it came

```
grep -irl gnome-keyring-daemon /etc
```

How to stop it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR** - add `only_if=xdm,gdm,kdm,sddm,lightdm,<your preferred DM>` after the line that ends with `[...] pam_gnome_keyring.so auto_start` in `/etc/pam.d/system-auth`.

It comes from `pam_gnome_keyring.so` being referenced in `/etc/pam.d/system-auth` (where it does not really belong), which in turn is sourced from several other PAM config files, so an instance of `gnome-keyring-daemon` is started every time you run `su` or `sudo`, for example:

```
[root@disclosure:~]# grep keyring /etc/pam.d/system-auth 
-auth       optional      pam_gnome_keyring.so
-session     optional      pam_gnome_keyring.so auto_start
```

Slackware specific discussion is [here](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/a-gnome-keyring-daemon-bug-4175704064/) and [here](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/requests-for-current-14-2-15-0-a-4175620463/page570.html#post6289809), official GNOME documentation is [here](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeKeyring/Pam).

Answer (score 0):

A workaround found...

```
removepkg gnome-keyring-daemon
```

But I prefer to disable it and know who try to start this process.

Answer (score 0):

@elbarna's suggestion doesn't work for me but `removepkg gnome-keyring-40.0-x86_64-1` does.